# PHP - unexpected end of file

Tags: php

I added the error reporting...still doesn't show up what the problem was. This is the code in my index.php

As you can see, I added some sort of alert if the user_ok returns...which does...

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./js/ajax.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<?php include_once("check-login.php"); ?>
<?php // if ($user_ok == true) { echo "true"; } ?>
<?php if ($user_ok == true): ?>
<div>
    <img src='./img/logo.png'><br>
    <form action='#' method='post'>
        <input type='text' maxlength='88' placeholder='Search'>
    </form>
</div>
<?php else: ?>
<div>
    <img src='./img/logo-horizontal.png'><br>
    <div>
    <!-- SOME CONTENT -->
    </div>  
</div>
<? endif; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did one of the answers below help resolve your question? If so, you should accept it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've opened your control structure using the traditional `<?php ?>` open-close tag, you'll need to close your conditional with th PHP tags:

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

Note that, per [the documentation](http://php.net/alternative_syntax):

> Mixing syntaxes in the same control block is not supported.

**Also**, note that the use of the `<? ?>` short tags is only enabled if `short_open_tag` is set equal to `TRUE` in your `php.ini`.

Answer (score 1):

see the

```
<? endif; ?>
```

it should be

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

`<? endif; ?>`

to

`<?php endif; ?>`